# Implementing captcha only once for one session

Tags: php, session, captcha

I've been working on a website which contains alot of links. I want to protect those links from bots/crawlers by implementing a CAPTCHA. I've tried reCAPTCHA by Google but it doesn't suit my needs(complex specially when it comes to people who are poor in English :P) plus I just want to stop the new programmers or crawlers, I know it can easily be broken by experienced programmers. So I searched and found this one to be good.

http://www.hardcode.nl/subcategory_4/article_243-simple-php-captcha-script.htm

Downloaded it and its working like a charm but my problem is :
 
1. I can see the index.html files checks the entered code and if correct redirects to write.php where session is created and output is shown. I want this to be done on the same page. Like when user enters correct code, he should be able to view the view the links on the same page to save bandwidth (I'll fetch them from mysql server)
 2. This is more important one, since I don't know anything about php sessions and php.net tutorials are just too short or next to nothing, can this be done that whenever a user input correct captcha once, he can see the links for rest of the time without captcha? And he will have to re-enter the captcha only when he closes the browser or after some interval like 10 minutes in case previous one can't be done. 
 Thank you

PS. I can use Javascript on my server but probably a php solution will be better since I'm also learning php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use AJAX to pull the links and then replace the HTML in the page.
2. Store a variable in the session that determines whether or not they've entered a CAPTCHA, then just check that before deciding whether to show the CAPTCHA or the links.

Comment: That was a exactly what I was looking for :)
Thanks it helped alot, just for knowledge sake, can you tell me if you can update page dynamically with php? 
@some other soul looking for same help in future, I've decided to use Ajax as Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams suggested, infact I'm using this captcha now :
http://www.webdesignbeach.com/beachbar/ajax-fancy-captcha-jquery-plugin

And here is more information on creating sessions(I really thought it would be more complex) :
http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php

Comment: You can't use PHP to update a page dynamically directly, but you can have it generate the appropriate JavaScript to XHR the server, as well as to write the script that responds to the XHR.